# An English Descriptive Word for Two Words

Tags: synonyms, american-english, syntactic-analysis, neologisms, descriptive-grammar

I'm currently after a synonym for "middle-aged". However, I'm needing the word to be appropriate to describe a non-living thing.

Middle-aged is more or less associated with animals and humans, not particularly describing research or articles.

If anyone has any suggestions other than "midlife", please comment.

Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Comment: Please supply a sample sentence where this term or expression would be used IN your question.  It will make everyone's lives much easier! :) May I also suggest modifying the title as "two words" could refer to any compound word in English

Comment: Ah, of course! Hahaha thank you. I'm trying to say "new, but not old research thats been conducted"...

Comment: Hello, welcome to EL&U. You say that you want the term to apply to 'a non-living _thing_' but you also say that you want it to be applicable to articles and reasearch. I can think of a few terms but not many of them would apply to everything including an eight-year old car, a four-year old laptop, a two-year old article on computing and a thirty-year old study into a rare medical condition. I suspect that you are more concerned with describing publications and research rather than objects, am I right?

Comment: Not a single word, but how about "relatively recent"? "Middle-aged" is quite a different concept to what you're asking about I think, because living things have a finite lifespan, but research doesn't.

Comment: In Red Dwarf, even the Universe had a mid-life crisis.

Comment: Related? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507089/word-for-not-recent-but-not-too-old

Comment: You ought not to use "midlife", either, because (as you say) the object is not living.

Answer (score 1):

The stage of forest growth between a young forest and an old-growth forest is called a **mature** one ([look for details here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-stages-of-early-to-mature-forest-stand-development-following-major-disturbances_fig1_284358345))

I believe that the same word can be applied to research. 
Here is an example:

> In many cases, this means that only **mature** research topics are considered appropriate for serious research inquiry. When research topics have **matured**, there is usually plenty of data...

[(source)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11747-017-0575-0)