# Word for not recent but not too old

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m needing a descriptive word that describes both not recent” and “not old” - essentially the latter.

However, I am not wanting to describe a living thing such a person or animal, but rather, academician.

I understand the complexity of this ask, given if there was a word, a quick google search would show a list. However, I’m also optimistic that given the broadness of the English language, a word meaning such would have to exist.

I would be absolutely over the moon if there is a word, but doesn’t use the words I’ve mentioned above,  so long as the point comes across.

The syntax I’m currently needing to word for is: “______[ Research highlights the important details of neurological disorders associated with transcriptional-translational feedback loops in RNA”.

Thank you all very much for your time in helping.

Comment: Well as I said in response to the [other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507086/an-english-descriptive-word-for-two-words), it's not one word, but how about "relatively recent"?

Comment: An *academician* is a member of an *academy*. Do you mean *academic*?

Comment: @Smock [*Academician*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/academician) is synonymous with *academic*. Although *both* have senses that involve living people (*I am an academic* or *I am an academician*)—so using either word to express something that isn't a living person is strange to me. At least without context. (And you're right that *academician* is only a noun. Only *academic* is a possible adjective.) Perhaps the question would be better served by saying *something scholarly*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I meant academic not as a person but as a synonym of *theoretical*. (See B2 https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/academic), but yes I suppose that would introduce ambiguity and could still be read as a person. (*Academician* always refers to a person, but Academic could be an adjective too). I wonder if *Research* as they use in their example would be a tighter fit. (I'm still not sure what the answer to the question is though!)

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate of ["An English Descriptive Word for Two Words"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507086/an-english-descriptive-word-for-two-words)?

Comment: @JasonBassford it does look very similar (even the context)

Comment: you could specify a time period like late 20th ot early 21st, since later readers may not know what recent or whatever means to you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **established** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/established) says

> **established**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Having existed or done something for a long time and therefore recognized and generally accepted.

The idea of **established** implies something that it is not new, but still relevant, and widely accepted as valid.

> Established research highlights the important details of neurological disorders associated with transcriptional-translational feedback loops in RNA.